# Google Apps Script: Error using getRange and getLastRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to write a Google Apps Script that creates a chart within a Google Spreadsheet. The chart should take a range of cells in the last row of the sheet. I have the following code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 11, 1, 4);
  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
  chartBuilder.addRange(range)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
    .setPosition(2, 2, 0, 0)
    .setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!');
  sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
```

The script creates a chart that displays the following error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

When I replace sheet.getLastRow() with an integer, the script works as intended. It seems that I'm not calling getLastRow() correctly, but I don't know why.

I have tried to search for similar problems, and it seems that similar errors were the result of the order in which variables were called. The examples that I found were much more complex, though, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like there is a very simple concept that I'm failing to grasp.

Regards,

Sean

Comment: Your code worked just fine in my test. Something else must be going on in your script, or your sheet... Try adding `Logger.log(range.getValues().toSource());` after your `var range=...` line, run your script and check the log output to see if it returned expected values. Something must be not quiet right there.

Comment: @azawaza Thank you for that suggestion. I added that code and realized that the function was returning an empty set. I deleted all of the "blank" rows from the bottom of the spreadsheet, and that seemed to do the trick.